# Quickest/most elegant way to verify a 2D array has same length per row?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

Let's say I have a 2D array:

```
const matrixRegular = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g'],
];
```

Let's say I want to verify that every row in this matrix has the same length, so the example above is a valid matrix, but the example below is not:

```
const matrixIrregular = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['e', 'f']
];
```

What's a clean/elegant way of doing it? This is the one-liner I have:

```
const isRegularMatrix = matrix => new Set(data.map(row => row.length)).size === 1
```

Convert the matrix to an array of just row length, then use `Set` to ensure every element is a duplicate (same length), hence it comes out with size 1.

Comment: If your matrix has 0 rows, your function will return false. Is this something you had considered already?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `every()` and compare `length` of each array with the length of the first.

```
const isRegularMatrix = matrix => matrix.every(x => x.length === matrix[0].length)
```

Comment: I think that `every()` tends to be a bit better, because it stops as soon as the first irregular row is found. `flat()` will have to go through all rows. All answers (including the one suggested by @Kousha) are O(n), though, where n is the number of rows, so I would choose the one which is easier to read and I think `every()` is also the best one. Edit: on second thought, `flat()` doesn't actually work. It would treat `[[1],[1,2,3],[1,2]]` as a valid matrix.

Comment: Agreed, for the sake of completeness, I would add a `matrix => matrix.length && matrix[0].constructor === Array && matrix.every(...)`

Comment: Maheer please fix your answer. `flat()` won't work (see my other comment).

Comment: @LucioPaiva Oh thanks for info I didn't thought of that. For that input `flat()` could never work. I removed that.

Comment: @MaheerAli also you have a typo. `martix.every` is spelled as martix, not matrix.

Comment: @Kousha in regards to your "for the sake of completeness", you're just removing a particular precondition from the call. In your question you have already stated that the input is known to be a 2D array, so the additional check you've suggested is unnecessary.